# PHP script seems to have started creating SQL entries on its own

Tags: php, mysql

*Ok, I have a very odd problem and I won't be capable of providing a good SO answer as I have no clue what is happening.*

Following issues are taking place at http://gw.mvctc.com/Class2018/smcintosh/registerlogin.php

I created a portfolio website for my Game Programming and Web Applications class and as a part of it we had to include a discussion board that implements the use of HTML5 Forms, PHP, and MySQL. Most of mine works beautifully, except that every so often a new account is created (I don't think it is by a person) with no information.

My SQL table for the users is created with this script:

```
<?php
require('conLocal.php');


$query = 'create table user (
        UserID INT AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key UNIQUE, 
        secLevel INT DEFAULT 1, 
        email VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE, 
        username VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE, 
        Password VARCHAR(64),
        rname VARCHAR(35),
        dateOfAction timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        DateActive timestamp);';

if ($con->query ( $query )) {
    echo '<h2>User Table created</h2>';
} else {
    echo '<h2>Error creating table: ' . $con->error . ' ' . $con->errno . '</h2>';
}

$con->close();
?>
```

The HTML Form:

```
        <form method="post" action="genUser.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Register</legend>

                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" required /><br />

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="Password" id="pass1" minlength="8" required /><br />

                <label>Re-enter Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="Password2" id="pass2"
                    minlength="8" required />

                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="rname" pattern="[a-zA-z]+[\w]{1}[a-zA-z]+"/><br />

                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" required /><br />

                <input type="Submit" value="Submit" style="width: 50%;"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

genUser.php:

```
<?php
require ('conLocal.php');

$email = HTMLSPECIALCHARS ( $_POST ['email'] );
$username = HTMLSPECIALCHARS ( $_POST ['username'] );
$Password = HTMLSPECIALCHARS ( $_POST ['Password'] );
$Password = md5 ( $Password );
$rname = HTMLSPECIALCHARS ( $_POST ['rname'] );

$sql = 'insert into user (email, username, Password, rname) values (?,?,?,?)';
$query = $con->prepare ( $sql );
$query->bind_param ( 'ssss', $email, $username, $Password, $rname );
if ($query->execute ()) {
    $message = "New account created for " . $rname;
    $sql = 'insert into notifications (UserID, message) values ("1", ?)';
    $query2 = $con->prepare ( $sql );
    $query2->bind_param ( 's', $message );

    if ($query2->execute ()) {
        // header ( "Refresh: 2; registerlogin.php" );
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Error creating table: ' . $con->error . ' ' . $con->errno . ' Test 1</h2>';
    }
    $sql = "select * from user where username='".$username."' and Password='".$Password."'";

    if ($result3 = $con->query($sql)) {
        $row = $result3->fetch_assoc ();
        $UserID = $row ['UserID'];
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Login Failure</h2><h4>Redirecting to register page...</h4>';
        //header ( "Refresh: 1; registerlogin.php" );
    }

    $sql = 'insert into notifications (UserID, message) values (?,"Hello, I would like to thank you for taking the time out of your day to explore the full functionality of my website. If you would like, look around my projects page and play some of the games I have worked on. I recently launched the discussion board functionality of this site, so feel free to post and interact with other members of this site. ~ Stephen McIntosh")';
    $query4 = $con->prepare ( $sql );
    $query4->bind_param ( 'i', $UserID );
    if ($query4->execute ()) {
        //header ( "Refresh: 0; registerlogin.php" );
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Error: ' . $con->error . ' ' . $con->errno . ' Test 2</h2>';
    }
    include 'logUser.php';
} else {
    echo '<h2>Error: ' . $con->error . ' ' . $con->errno . ' Test 3</h2>';
    require 'registerlogin.php';
}
?>
```

If I understand the way HTML works, it should be completely impossible to create an account with no data in the email, password, password2, or username fields. So how can I have users that seem to be created automatically and be blank, except for the UserID value?

*I really wish that I could give more Info, but I am absolutely lost here. I don't think this is a logic or syntax error.* **Really anything you can give me to go off of to try to logic my way out of this issue is appreciated.**

Comment: Don't rely entirely on client-side validation. It's *entirely* possible to submit incorrect values. Validate server side. Provide client-side validation *only* as a helpful guide for the user, not for validation.

Comment: Values can easily be manipulated client-side after a user has submitted a form, by manipulating their `$_POST` data. You will need to validate on the server, and show us your **insertion** script, not just your creation script ;)

Comment: Man, the question title *really* oversells the question contents.

Comment: @ceejayoz i thought this is troll question.. i got excited for a second

Comment: you want to validate using server for multiple reasons. 1, it's easy to bypass client validation. and 2, if you do client and server validation, you need to maintain both in sync. its easier to just validate using server.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Note: Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default for your fields unless you have a compelling reason to restrict otherwise. For example, an email address will *frequently* be well beyond the arbitrary 25 character limit you have there.

Comment: @tadman Thank you, and I will keep this all in mind once I move onto a real world scenario. As for this project, I was using MD5 and doing this on my own, because it is an assignment for class and my teacher wants to see what we are capable of doing.

Comment: There's no excuse to use MD5. It looks awful and it's only going to distract from the real problems. Use [`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) at the absolute minimum. It's easy to use and *is* secure. If you want to demonstrate what you're capable of doing, do it the right way and your code will look a lot better. It's not a big change.

Comment: I will definitely look into that, Thank you for the advice.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. You've done this for some queries, but do it for all.

Comment: Can you tell me which SQL statement I did that with? I can't find it.

Comment: Another thing (sorry!): `htmlspecialchars` is intended to be used *only* when you're displaying data. It's not something you should use when inserting into the database. Whatever you put in there should be clean, raw, and in whatever canonical form is appropriate (e.g. leading and traling space trimmed, etc.). When you display something you'll want to escape for the specific context in which it appears: HTML, JavaScript, JSON, plain-text and XML are all common situations. Each has an associated escaping function.

Comment: The `$result3` one is not prepared properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145076/discussion-between-lordbug-and-tadman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing what your `genUser.php` script does it's impossible to tell, but: The HTML `required` attribute does not prevent anyone from posting empty data to your server!

1. The browser needs to support and enforce `required`, otherwise it does nothing.
2. When the form is submitted, a plain HTTP request is created and sent to the server. **You do not need a browser to send an HTTP request.** HTTP requests can be sent in a million different ways directly to your server without going through your HTML form and most certainly without heeding the `required` attribute.

My guess would be that a bot or search engine spider happens to hit your `genUser.php` page, which **does no data validation** and just inserts an empty row.

The solution here is to validate the data on your server before you attempt to save it to the database.

Comment: Please review the genUser.php script I have added.

Comment: Well, yep, it confirms what I said.

Comment: Ok, so what validation would I add to make this more secure? and would it be enough to add `NOT NULL` to the createUser.php script?

Comment: At the most basic level, you'll want to add some `if` checks: `if (empty($_POST['email'])) die('Email required');`. You may then want to progress to more complete data validation, e.g. using [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php). Finally, if the data is insufficient, you output the same HTML form again with added "Please enter an email address" etc. to fields where data is missing.

Comment: Also, your use of `HTMLSPECIALCHARS` is bad there; you'll want to read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that. In the meantime is there anything I can do about the bot which is creating the accounts?

Comment: …validate your data **and don't insert it into the database when there is no data!?**

Answer (score 0):

Any time the script is called, regardless of where it is called from, it will execute and POST is simply a blank array by default.

While I recommend further validation, at a minimum you can wrap the code from genUser.php in a `if(!empty($_POST)){....}`

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    require ('conLocal.php');

    $email = HTMLSPECIALCHARS ( $_POST ['email'] );
    $username = HTMLSPECIALCHARS ( $_POST ['username'] );
    $Password = HTMLSPECIALCHARS ( $_POST ['Password'] );
    $Password = md5 ( $Password );
    $rname = HTMLSPECIALCHARS ( $_POST ['rname'] );

    $sql = 'insert into user (email, username, Password, rname) values(?,?,?,?)';
    $query = $con->prepare ( $sql );
    $query->bind_param ( 'ssss', $email, $username, $Password, $rname );
    if ($query->execute ()) {
        $message = "New account created for " . $rname;
        $sql = 'insert into notifications (UserID, message) values ("1", ?)';
        $query2 = $con->prepare ( $sql );
        $query2->bind_param ( 's', $message );

        if ($query2->execute ()) {
        // header ( "Refresh: 2; registerlogin.php" );
            } else {
                echo '<h2>Error creating table: ' . $con->error . ' ' . $con->errno . ' Test 1</h2>';
        }
    $sql = "select * from user where username='".$username."' and Password='".$Password."'";

    if ($result3 = $con->query($sql)) {
        $row = $result3->fetch_assoc ();
        $UserID = $row ['UserID'];
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Login Failure</h2><h4>Redirecting to register page...</h4>';
        //header ( "Refresh: 1; registerlogin.php" );
    }

    $sql = 'insert into notifications (UserID, message) values (?,"Hello, I would like to thank you for taking the time out of your day to explore the full functionality of my website. If you would like, look around my projects page and play some of the games I have worked on. I recently launched the discussion board functionality of this site, so feel free to post and interact with other members of this site. ~ Stephen McIntosh")';
    $query4 = $con->prepare ( $sql );
    $query4->bind_param ( 'i', $UserID );
    if ($query4->execute ()) {
        //header ( "Refresh: 0; registerlogin.php" );
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Error: ' . $con->error . ' ' . $con->errno . ' Test 2</h2>';
    }
    include 'logUser.php';
} else {
    echo '<h2>Error: ' . $con->error . ' ' . $con->errno . ' Test 3</h2>';
    require 'registerlogin.php';
}
    }
```

.